# document.all('data').XMLDocument not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I just want my application to work in IE 9 without using compatibility mode, we are using `document.all('data').XMLDocument` for getting the data in the code. In IE 8 its working fine but in IE 9 its not working. I have tried using `document.getElementById` but of no use. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I *implore* you not to use `document.all` unless you're using IE4 or something like that.

Comment: Adding to @Qantas94Heavy's comment, MSDN states unequivocally that [`document.all` is no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx). Do you have a small demo that shows the issue between IE 8 and IE 9?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: yes i agree with you but the code was developed long back and we have to make this work in IE9.

Comment: @harini Can you share with us a demo? It would greatly improve the chances of getting a more rapid and reliable response.

Comment: What is the alternative to using document.all in such a case? @Qantas94Heavy